# Fullpage.js normalScrollElements VS keyboardScrolling

Tags: scroll, overflow, keyboard-events, fullpage.js

I'm a very happy fullpage.js user.
There's just a last issue I want to fix before saying my website is complete.

I have an issue with normalScrollElements and keyboardScrolling.

My ABOUT page is a page that overlay the fullpage one and when I use the keyboard arrows, to scroll the ABOUT page, it still scroll the page behind it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fullpage.js doesn't provide a way to do it.

fullpage.js is using slimScroll plugin for the `scrollOverflow` feature and slimScroll doesn't provide a way to scroll using the keyboard.

You would have to modify slimScroll first, as suggested in [this pull request](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/issues/191), and then probably use `setKeyboardScrolling(false)` in fullpage.js once you load that section/slide. You can turn it on again in `onLeave`.